# How to keep data available for whole project access?

Tags: c#

Well. I have done a small project.

But the problem is some of my required data is not available across whole project.

I mean, every time I go form to form I need to open the database and fill the same data from the same SqlDataAdapter.

Instead is it possible to keep the data somewhere globally for all the project forms?

With my project I have a class for the queries and tables and wherever I need data in the forms, there I use to call the Subs for filling the table like the below...

```
Class1.cs
=========
public void MyTableFill()
       {
            Con.ConnectionString = Con_1;
            Con.Open();
            SQLDAp = new SqlDataAdapter(MyQry, Con);
            SQLDAp.Fill(MyTable);
            Con.Close();
        }

Form1.cs
========
Class1 MyDatas = new Class1();

Form1_Load()
        {
            MyDatas.MyTableFill();
        }

Form2.cs
========
Class1 AccDatas=new Class1();

Form2_Load()
        {
            AccDatas.MyTableFill();
        }
```

Thanks

Comment: are you really sure you wish to do this? global state is discourage for good reasons.

Comment: You want to start using a proper naming scheme. Calling your classes Class1 and form1 and similar will soon make it impossible for any one to read/maintain the code

Comment: Iam not clear, Can u pls. explain me the reason...Why should we call in all forms , for permanent datas.?  Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to to is

a) in your opening form initialize and fill the adapter

b) make a constructor that accepts the adapter in all other forms

c) pass the adapter from one form to the next as a argument

PS: You may also pass the adapter as a reference, that way any changes are saved.

Comment: It's a reference type so it's going to be a reference that's passed no matter what you do